# jar execution on unix gives error initializing quantum renderer :no suitable pipeline found

Tags: java, selenium, unix, javafx

I am trying to run a selenium jar project, with implementation of headless jbrowser. I have javafx library in the directory which I have provide as classpath.
When I try to run it gives error.
I used below command.

```
/sbcimp/run/tp/sun/jdk/v1.8.0_144/bin/java -cp "/home/jamesmb/selenium/javafx-src/com" -jar /home/jamesmb/selenium/ratesTestUnixv3.jar
```

error :

```
/sbcimp/run/tp/sun/jdk/v1.8.0_144/bin/java -cp "/home/jamesmb/selenium/javafx-src/com" -jar /home/jamesmb/selenium/ratesTestUnixv3.jar
/home/jamesmb
[2018-08-28T11:15:03.689][Instance 1][Port 45076] Graphics Device initialization failed for :  sw
[2018-08-28T11:15:03.692][Instance 1][Port 45076] Error initializing QuantumRenderer: no suitable pipeline found
[2018-08-28T11:15:03.692][Instance 1][Port 45076] java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error initializing QuantumRenderer: no suitable pipeline found
[2018-08-28T11:15:03.692][Instance 1][Port 45076]       at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer.getInstance(QuantumRenderer.java:280)
[2018-08-28T11:15:03.692][Instance 1][Port 45076]       at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.init(QuantumToolkit.java:221)
[2018-08-28T11:15:03.692][Instance 1][Port 45076]       at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.getToolkit(Toolkit.java:205)
[2018-08-28T11:15:03.692][Instance 1][Port 45076]       at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.startup(PlatformImpl.java:209)
[2018-08-28T11:15:03.692][Instance 1][Port 45076]       at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.startToolkit(LauncherImpl.java:675)
[2018-08-28T11:15:03.693][Instance 1][Port 45076]       at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:695)
[2018-08-28T11:15:03.693][Instance 1][Port 45076]       at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$155(LauncherImpl.java:182)
[2018-08-28T11:15:03.693][Instance 1][Port 45076]       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
[2018-08-28T11:15:03.693][Instance 1][Port 45076] Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error initializing QuantumRenderer: no suitable pipeline found
[2018-08-28T11:15:03.693][Instance 1][Port 45076]       at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer$PipelineRunnable.init(QuantumRenderer.java:94)
[2018-08-28T11:15:03.693][Instance 1][Port 45076]       at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer$PipelineRunnable.run(QuantumRenderer.java:124)
[2018-08-28T11:15:03.693][Instance 1][Port 45076]       ... 1 more
[2018-08-28T11:15:03.694][Instance 1][Port 45076] java.lang.RuntimeException: No toolkit found
[2018-08-28T11:15:03.694][Instance 1][Port 45076]       at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.getToolkit(Toolkit.java:217)
[2018-08-28T11:15:03.695][Instance 1][Port 45076]       at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.startup(PlatformImpl.java:209)
[2018-08-28T11:15:03.695][Instance 1][Port 45076]       at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.startToolkit(LauncherImpl.java:675)
[2018-08-28T11:15:03.695][Instance 1][Port 45076]       at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:695)
[2018-08-28T11:15:03.695][Instance 1][Port 45076]       at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$155(LauncherImpl.java:182)
[2018-08-28T11:15:03.695][Instance 1][Port 45076]       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
[2018-08-28T11:15:03.695][Instance 1][Port 45076]
```

Comment: Add stacktrace as text not as screenshot

Comment: I guess, you application Need an X11 Server wich is not running

Comment: hi added the stack trace

Answer (score 0):

Error was because of a 64 bit executable trying to run on a 32 bit java environment, also missing gtk library